# Fetching tags with selenium href within a class name

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to using selenium. I am using selenium to extract the links of google search results. I want to take all the links from the search results. this is what the html looks like where the link type that I want to extract is found in the <a href= >:

```
<div class='r'>
   <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/thu-huong-trish-nguyen-7bba5722" ping="/url?
   sa=t&amp;source=web&amp;rct=j&amp;url=https://www.linkedin.com/in/thu-huong-trish-nguyen-
   7bba5722&amp;ved=2ahUKEwiqw5D0qt3rAhVG7J4KHd3GBbQQFjAAegQIAxAB"><br><h3 class="LC20lb 
   DKV0Md">Thu-Huong (Trish) Nguyen - Research Data Analyst II - LinkedIn</h3><div class="TbwUpd
   NJjxre"><cite class="iUh30 gBIQub bc tjvcx">www.linkedin.com<span class="eipWBe"> › ...    </span></cite></div></a>
```

The rest of the results have the exact same class type and form, I essentially want the https://www.linkedin.com link.  I did this as an attempt

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.get_attribute("href"))
```

this worked wonderful, I am pretty much extracting all the links on the google search results, however the only problem is that I only want the link types I specified. My code returns the links that I want and great deal of links that I do not want.

A solution that I thought would work perfect is it were possible to use the fact that all these links fall within the class type r.

I tried incorporating the r into the driver.find_elements but have not found any solutions online.

Any ideas

Comment: @arundeepchohan I did the following elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[(@class,'r')]/a") and got the error that the string is not a valid Xpath expression

Comment: I am not quite understanding, I got an error saying the expression is not valid. and the script will not evaluate now. did I do something wrong?

Comment: //div[(@class, 'r')]//a[@href] try that

Comment: @arundeepchohan I still got the same error

Comment: I do not belief that it is, the class name stays the same and is consistent all throughout the page. If I search for something else the same class name stands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPath will help you to get all the `a` tags containing `https://www.linkedin.com` in `href`.

```
//div[@class='g']//div[@class='r']/a[contains(@href, 'https://www.linkedin.com')]
```

Comment: why did you include the//div[@class='g'] portion? if I excluded it I got web elements, however upon including it I got the proper links that I wanted. Further why does this work in general?

Comment: if you want you can exclude the `//div[@class='g']`. I dint get it? `Further why does this work in general?`

Comment: No I ran the code without the ```//div[@class='g']``` and it didn't work so its needed. I was wondering about the syntax, why is it the way it is?

Comment: This is related to relative XPath, `//` means it can started from anywhere in DOM where div is having `class='g'`and the next div is descendant of this div. contains is used to check the attribute having a value. You can explore more about XPath from here [Link](https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/complete-guide-for-using-xpath-in-selenium-with-examples/)